# Make sure this equipment can do what I want (infrared decoding)

Tags: arduino, oscilloscope, infrared

I'm CS but took a digital electronics physics class at my old university and found it really interesting so I wouldn't mind having my own small EE workshop. For my main project I just want to decode infrared signal for a gated community gate clicker so that I can write an Android app to retransmit it from my S5.

I just need this list of components checked over to make sure if this is all the equipment I will need for my main project.

- Breadboard & Micro: Arduino Starter Kit
- Oscilloscope:
  [http://www.amazon.com/Huhushop-TM-Digital-Storage-Oscilloscope/dp/B00GD6BYDM/ref=sr_1_53?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1398097080&sr=1-53&keywords=oscilloscope](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00GD6BYDM)
- IR demodulator:
  Digi-Key part # TSOP57238TT1TR-ND

This is the tutorial I want to follow:

http://www.eevblog.com/forum/blog/eevblog-506-ir-remote-control-arduino-protocol-tutorial/

Comment: IR for a gated community? Are you sure? Most remote controlled gates and doors are RF, not IR.

Comment: the clicker has a little LED looking emitter on it

Comment: so you have to aim the clicker at the gate?

Comment: yupppppppppppppp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 - You'll go blind trying to read that scope. It only has 128 pixels horizontally, which is not nearly enough to resolve the codes you'll be looking at. What you may find more cost-effective is a logic analyzer. At a guess, this should do you: [http://www.amazon.com/24Mhz-Channel-analyzer-Saleae-Compatible/dp/B00C0Q5NOU/ref=sr_1_2?s=pc&ie=UTF8&qid=1398100701&sr=1-2&keywords=logic+analyzer](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00C0Q5NOU) You connect it to a PC and use the PC monitor as the display. In this case, I suspect you'll have to go to the manufacturer's web site to get the software for it.

2 - The demodulator you've chosen is a bare, surface mount chip. Lots of luck trying to connect to it. You'll have more luck with [http://www.amazon.com/Velleman-IR-Demodulator-Sensor/dp/B001M1991W/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1398100978&sr=8-2&keywords=ir+demodulator](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001M1991W) Also bear in mind that this will only work for 38 KHz emitters. Granted, that is far and away the most common frequency used - but it's not guaranteed. Although, for $1 (plus shipping) you won't be hurting too badly if it's the wrong type.

3 - You'll need some perf board to mount your detector to, and a power supply for it - minimum 5 volts at a few hundred mA. You'll also need some clip leads to connect the demodulator to the power supply.

Comment: Thank you so much for replying.  I have a couple questions.  1. Is that basically an oscillator but the output is displayed on the PC?   2. I'm glad you told me, would have sucked to buy something like that.  3.  I'm pretty sure the Arduino starter kit will have all of that stuff? (http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoStarterKit)

Comment: No, #1 is a box that samples several lines at regular intervals to produce a 0 or 1 for each line. This means that you have to set a comparator level to determine the difference between 0 and 1. For CMOS logic, 0 to 5 volts, you set the threshold at 2.5 volts. The sampled data gets sent to the PC, and the PC basically makes an oscilloscope trace out of the data. A logic analyzer typically has a whole bunch of other functions, like triggering on a specified combination of data bits, but you don't need to worry about that.

Comment: As for #3, (shrug) I have no idea.

Comment: Oops. I think that when you asked "Is that basically an oscillator" you meant "Is that basically an oscilloscope". In which case the answer is yes, and you can disregard the rest of my first answer. Sorry.

Comment: No problem, the error was in my use of terminology.

Comment: A 38khz demodulator will work for other freq carrier waves, just not as well. Mainly a function of power/distance from the transmitting led. Just fyi.